# pam / ad issues with server-based application

Tags: 16.04, authentication, pam, active-directory

Following the 16.04 upgrade we had some pam / ad issues which were solved based on community answers (ie lockscreen, authentication).

We now have a new and critical one. We run a lot of [RStudio Server](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/) instances.  But we now get locked out with messages such as

```
May 24 16:10:10 serverXYZ rserver-pam[3632]: ERROR pam_acct_mgmt failed: \
   Permission denied; LOGGED FROM: \
   virtual int rstudio::core::system::PAM::login(const string&, const string&) \
   /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/core/system/Pam.cpp:196
```

This is clearly the application, but then again the application had been running for several years and several Ubuntu upgrades with this pam / ad setup.

Any idea what I may need to add to the pam and/or sssd config files similar to the

```
ad_gpo_map_interactive = +unity, +polkit-1
```

line we added?

*Edit on 2016-05-27:*  Following Ian's suggestion, here is the `pamtester` output:

```
xyz@serverXYZ:~$ sudo pamtester --verbose rstudio someuser authenticate acct_mgmt
pamtester: invoking pam_start(rstudio, someuser, ...)
pamtester: performing operation - authenticate
Password: 
pamtester: successfully authenticated
pamtester: performing operation - acct_mgmt
pamtester: Permission denied
xyz@serverXYZ:~$
```

So it authenticates, but is still denied.  Any idea what could be the cause?

Also see my [related question on PAM and cron](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777912/pam-ad-issue-with-cron) which is equally frustrating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the section for your domain in /etc/sssd/sssd.conf add

```
ad_gpo_map_service = +rstudio
```

Comment: Awesome -- this did the trick.  Thanks so much (and sorry for the delay -- I was gone for a few days).

Comment: Would you by chance have an idea what this very related issue (for `cron`) would need?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/777912/pam-ad-issue-with-cron

Answer (score 1):

Try running [pamtester](http://pamtester.sourceforge.net/) and see if that gives more information about where PAM is failing (this will also show if its occurring outside of RStudio or not):

`sudo pamtester --verbose rstudio <username> authenticate acct_mgmt`

Comment: thanks so much, most helpful.  I'll append the output to my question.  It is a little puzzling.